# array insert into database

Tags: php

guys im trying to make a list of students in php and getting each of its value and insert it in the database.

```
$b_lname = $_POST['bstudnt_lname'];
$b_fname = $_POST['bstudnt_fname'];
$b_mname = $_POST['bstudnt_mname'];

$department = $_POST['class_department'];
$section = $_POST['section_name'];
$year_grade = $_POST['faclty_advse_year'];

$school_id ="a3arew542q3dq";

$counter2 = 0;

$button = $_POST['add_students'];

if(isset($button)){

    foreach($b_lname as $blast => $x){ 
        $arraylname[] ="".$x;
        }  
    foreach($b_fname as $bfirst => $y){
            $arrayfname[] ="".$y;
            $counter2+=1;
        }
    foreach($b_mname as $bmid => $z){
            $arraymname[] ="".$z;
            $counter2+=1;
        }   



        for($v=0;$v<=$counter2-1;$v++){

            if($arrayfname[$v]!="" && $arraymname[$v]="" &&   $arraylname[$v]=""){

            $insert = "INSERT INTO  students(school_id,firstname,middlename,lastname,gender,department,section,year_grade) 
           VALUES('$school_id','$arrayfname[$v]','$arraymname[$v]','$arraylname[$v]','male','$department','$section','$year_grade')";

                  if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
                    die('error insert'.mysql_error());


                    }
            }



        }
```

}

but im having trouble if the array has no value it wont insert in the database.
i made an if statement but i guess its no use.

Comment: why do u want to insert empty values into the DB?

Comment: also, are middlename, lastname primary keys?

Comment: i mean it wont insert in the DB if its empty. sorry.

Comment: ok, as Travesty mentioned, conditional statments need to have 2 `==` or `===` equality signs in `if($arrayfname[$v]!="" && $arraymname[$v]=="" &&   $arraylname[$v]==""){`

Comment: im getting an error of Undefined offset which has if($arraygfname[$v]!="" && $arraygmname[$v]!="" && $arrayglname[$v]!=""){ what the problem with it?

Comment: that's coz the indexes for `$arraygfname[$v]` are not defined. check the value for `$arraygfname[$v]` right before the for loop and see if all the indexes that are used in the loop, are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if($arrayfname[$v]!="" && $arraymname[$v]="" &&   $arraylname[$v]=""){
```

You are using a single `=` for the second two conditionals. Change them to `==` or `===`.

Comment: aww yes.. its working finally.. getting confused with conditions. this thesis sucks!

Comment: On a side note, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions. As [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) states, you should use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($array)) {
  //insert into db
} else {
  // array is emtpy
}
```